# What happened to cause the events of Flight 7500?

Tags: flight-7500

I watched this movie at a friend's house, and thought it was freaky/original/cool. In it,

> everyone on board has died. A group believing to be alive is tormented by a Shinigami, which is actually a good thing-taking them to the afterlife.

What happens that causes the fate of those passengers? I don't fly much, so I'm a little confused on what exactly happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen the film, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_7500)

> Flight 7500 suffered a catastrophic decompression, communication had been lost, and a fighter jet has confirmed the death of everyone on board.

According to [Moviepooper](http://www.moviepooper.com/12/5972Flight75002014.html):

> A bout of turbulence shown earlier in the film, caused the breakage of a critical seal. This damage caused an immediate decompression of the entire plane. The oxygen masks malfunctioned which lead the immediate deaths of the flight crew and all passengers abroad the plane.

A licensed pilot told [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/Health/planes-cabin-depressurizes/story?id=25277752) that when a plane's cabin depressurizes:

> "What happens first is your brain is not as quick. You’d get very
>   confused and stop thinking clearly,” he explained. “Then you’d fall
>   asleep and eventually die due to lack of oxygen."

Basically the pressure outside the plane is much lower, so all of the air rushes out of the cabin (to achieve equilibrium with the outside air).

Comment: Is decompression just another word for Suffocation? or is that something else...Not familiar with how that would kill?